# NodeJS Firebase Functions Fails After Deployment

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, cors, google-cloud-functions

I have a NodeJS and using Firebase functions. When running on localhost it is sending the expected JSON. After I deploy it to Firebase I'm getting the following error when trying to hit the endpoint:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined
    at getErrorDetails (/worker/worker.js:365:14)
    at logAndSendError (/worker/worker.js:579:12)
    at process.<anonymous> (/worker/worker.js:854:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:108:22)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:230:7)
```

The front end returns the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vear-node.firebaseapp.com/xmlfeed' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I doubt this is a CORS issue though because I'm using Express cors middleware and hitting other endpoints on this server with no issue.

Code:

```
const app = express().use(cors());

app.get('/xmlfeed', cors(), async (request, response) => {
    const feedResponse = await getXMLFeedData();
    const json = { products: feedResponse };
    response.json(json);
});
```

```
export const getXMLFeedData = async (): Promise<any> => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://www.nae-vegan.com/extend/catalog_81.xml');

        const parsedResponse = await parseXMLResult(response);
        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(parsedResponse);
        const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        const formatted = await formatNAEProducts(jsonObject);

        return Promise.resolve(formatted);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};
```

```
const parseXMLResult = async (response: any): Promise<any> => {
    var parsedResult: any = undefined;

    try {
        await parser.parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
            parsedResult = result;
        });

        return Promise.resolve(parsedResult);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};
```

endpoint: `https://vear-node.firebaseapp.com/xmlfeed`

Does anyone know what could make the error happen after deployment by work perfectly fine locally?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal code that exhibits the problem.  Right now we can't see what `getXMLFeedData()` does, nor is there any code that shows a property called `stack`.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated the question with more code. There is no property called stack, which is why I'm confused as to where it comes from.

Comment: It comes from express. @dcotter did you solve the problem? Do you remember how?

Answer (score -1):

You have to allow all the cors origin requests into your header. since you're using express framework you have to include it in your app.use method. check the code below.

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
});
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a CORS issue. Adding those headers produces the same error. 

I'm also using Express CORS like this `const app = express().use(cors());`, which enables all CORS requests https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html